# How to replace delimiters from a string in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have the following data

```
abc
pqr  
xyz,
jkl mno
```

This is one string separated by delimiters like space, new line, comma, tab.
There could be two or more consecutive spaces or tabs or any delimiter after or before a word.

I would like to be able to do the following

1. Get the individual words removing all leading and trailing delimiters off it
2. Append the individual words with "OR"

I am trying to achieve this to build a T-SQL query separated by `OR` clause.

Thanks

Comment: And you need to do this parsing and building *in T-SQL*? Why?

Comment: what language are you using to perform this string manipulation?

Comment: Not programming language. I would like to be able to do this in DBMS, SQL

Comment: @Aaron- I did this using workflows(we have workflow tool). however, it is good for words up to 1000 but as the list grows, the application hangs because it has to call APIs in loop,it cant handle it. I think SQL may be able to handle up to 10000 transaction with no issue

Comment: Well, good luck, you'll be using loops of some kind in SQL Server too, it doesn't have any native string handling methods for this, and even if it did, your programming language of choice would be better at it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can achieve what you need (although I think using a programming language is way better) using just SQL, here is my approach.

*Kindly note that I will just handle commas, newlines and multiple-spaces, but you can simple follow using the same technique to remove the rest of your undesired  characters*

so let's assume that we have a table names `ExampleData` with a column named `DataBefore` and another called `DataAfter`.

`DataBefore`: has the line value that you want to clean
`DataAfter`: will host the cleaned text

First we need to trim the preceding & leading space(s) from the text

`Update ExampleData
set DataAfter = LTRIM(RTRIM(DataBefore))`

Second, we should clean all the commas, and replace them with spaces (doesn't matter if we will end up with many spaces together)

`Update ExampleData
set DataAfter = replace(replace(DataAfter,',',' '),char(13),' ')`

---

**This is the part in which you may continue and remove any other characters using the same technique, and replace it by a space**

---

So far we have a text that has no spaces before or after, and every comma, newline,  **TAB, dash, etc** character replaced by a space, let's continue our cleaning procedure.

We can now safely move on to replace the spaces between words with just one, this is made by using the following SQL statement:

`Update ExampleData
set DataAfter = replace(replace(replace(DataAfter,' ','<>'),'><',''),'<>',' ')`

as per your needs, we need to place an OR between each word, this is achievable with this SQL statement:

`Update ExampleData
set DataAfter = replace(replace(replace(DataAfter,' ','<>'),'><',''),'<>',' OR ')`

we are done now, as a final step that may or may not make a change, we need to remove any space at the end of the whole text, just in case an unwanted character was at the end of the text and as a result got replaced by a space, this can be achieved by the following statement:

`Update ExampleData
set DataAfter = RTRIM(DataAfter)`

we are now done. :)

as a test, I've generated the following text inside the `DataBefore` column:
`this is just      a, test,  to    be sure, that everything   is, working, great     .`

and after running the previous commands, ended up with this value inside the `DataAfter` column:
`this OR is OR just OR a OR test OR to OR be OR sure OR that OR everything OR is OR working OR great OR .`

Hope that this is what you want, let me know if you need any extra help :)

Comment: This is very helpful! Let me try that out, I was looking for exactly the same thing!

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks much!

Comment: I'm glad that this was helpful for you, kindly don't forget to mark it as answer if this answer has fixed the problem :)